# how to manage enable / unenable status across related models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say for example I have a Location and an Event and they operate like the following:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  default_scope  { where is_enabled: true }

end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  default_scope  { where is_enabled: true }
end
```

The problem that I have is that I could have events that are enabled but that the location becomes unenabled. In this situation, do I need to update all the other columns to reflect this (ie set all the events' is_enabled to false that have the location_id of that specific location). I'm thinking of creating a class called like LocationManager that will have a method called unenable that will manage all these relationship's enabling and unenabling. Are there other ideas on how to manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a callback on `Location` which would update the `is_enabled` field for all associated `Event` objects, if the `is_enabled` field changed to `false` on the given `Location` instance:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  default_scope  { where is_enabled: true }

  after_update :disable_corresponding_locations, :if => lambda { self.is_enabled_changed? && self.is_enabled == false }

  private

  def disable_corresponding_locations
    self.events.map {|event| event.update_attributes :is_enabled => false }
  end

end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  default_scope  { where is_enabled: true }
end
```

This way, you could create another callback on `after_update` which could re-enable all `Event` objects associated with a `Location`, if so desired.

Comment: hmm.. that makes sense. would probably name it disable_corresponding_events for clarity. I realized there's actually a lot more that will need to be managed but I think this gets me on the right track. Thx!